# Issue in compiling Java file

Tags: java

I created a JSP project. After that I tried to run a Java file with several user defined packages. I got the following errors:

```
//ecommerce contains main function that call several packages
Ecommerce.java:13: error:
   package com.ideas2it.ecommerce.service.implementaion does not exist
```

Comment: Please share your jsp code.

Comment: @DarkKnight `error:.. does not exist` maybe there's no code at all.

Comment: `implementaion` - shouldn't that maybe be `implementation`?

Comment: @Dukeling ni. it should be like that

Comment: @Pravin : Good, finally you managed to run your application. Govan Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude there might be some problem with your class path.

Try compiling it like below.

> javac -cp . filename.java

Answer (score 0):

You must be following a tutorial, the error seems to be with the existence of package. You need to create a package named com.ideas2it.ecommerce.service.implementaion and add necessary files to it.